# how to avoid duplication of tickets in nsf?

Tags: duplicates, lotus-notes, lotusscript, ticket-tracking

I have more than one application server for smooth access but unfortunate at time i faced problem of duplication in tickets:
my current scenario generates ticket no. after the completion of form at save events but sometime due to server issues , replication delays hence two ticket generated of same no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this question is way to broad as it does not show the minimum amount of research...

Nevertheless I will answer it: Here are some ways to solve this issue.

The easiest: Add a Servername to the ticket-number.

So count as you do, but if there are duplicates, then they are different by there servername part:

Server1-0001
Server1-0002
Server2-0003
Server3-0004
Server1-0005
Server2-0005

Another possibility is to create the number only on ONE server. You can either do this by having an agent on that server running on all documents that do not have a number yet or "asking" the server for a number when saving.

First is easy to implement, but on the servers that do not create the numbers it will take at most 2 replication intervals for a ticket to get its unique number.

Second is trickier as you need all servers to "know" one central server and write code / agents / whatever to "get" a ticket number from that server and put it in the ticket.

All of this is not trivial and therefor to broad to answer in detail here.

Comment: Adding on to what @Torsten said, getting a sequential number in an environment that's designed to be distributed is hard.  If you Google "Domino sequential numbers" you'll find lots of ideas, but none of them are simple and all of them have pitfalls.

Comment: Or put the server number at the end, e.g. if there are 2 servers, one will use even numbers and the other odd numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, so much valuable high-quality Domino-related content seems to have dropped off the internet lately, including Andre Guirard's comprehensive treatment of this very subject from way back when, that it's getting to be increasingly difficult for relative newbies to research their questions. <Sigh/>

Comment: @Torsten your idea of including Server Name in Ticket is easy and implementable , as far as second is concern  it is good but raise problem if server is down who is responsible for creating tickets and caller will receive the ticket no. later .It might face acceptance issue due to change in routine task  by user.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz: I agree with you Sir, it becomes sometime difficult to take help from internet .I found domino Help more valuable ,but some time we have different scenario which need discussion and exchange of ideas. Unfortunately , internet community lacks in such tech group specifically for Notes Domino

Comment: I know a company that uses @Unique to generate invoice numbers, and no customer has ever complained.

Comment: @PhilMJones does it generate in a sequence??

Comment: @ramsha No.but they were sorted by creation date/time, so the reference number wasn't needed to be sequential, just unique.